# Accessing Commands without modifying ribbon in Visio?

Tags: microsoft-visio

Is there a way to access commands that aren't in the ribbon, without having to modify the ribbon?

I often see instructions like this that require modifying the ribbon to access a rarely used command:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-venn-diagram-447d65f4-79a3-411d-811d-bfdea7f83e2d

There was a day you could drill into menus and find anything without having to modify the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

It is still possible to have the classical menus back in Visio and generally
in Office, via commercial third-party products.

Here are the two such products that I know of:

- [UBitMenu](http://www.ubit.ch/software/ubitmenu-languages/)
  (free for private use, or €10 base fee +  €0.65 per user)
- [Addintools Classic Menu for Visio](https://www.addintools.com/office2010/visio/index.html)
  (trialware $25)